# Qt mouse events not working in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, mouse, mousemove

I am using Qt 5.7 (the latest version). I can't get the mouse events to work in QGraphicsScene, but they work in window outside of my scene. I have followed this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397217/qt-mousemove-not-functioning/16397761#16397761)

So I have  overwritten `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()` in my main widget's subclass like this:

```
// header:
class MyWidget {
    ...
    void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * event );
};

// source:
MyWidget::MyWidget() {
    setMouseTracking();
}

void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent * event ) {

}
```

It doesn't work for: `mouseMoveEvent`, `mouseGrabber`, `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, or `mouseDoubleClickEvent`. But somehow it only works for `mousePressEvent`.

Could this be a bug in Qt?

**SOURCE CODE:**
In objectloader.cpp

```
ObjectLoader::ObjectLoader(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ObjectLoader)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
   scene=new QGraphicsScene(this);
   ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
   ui->graphicsView->setMouseTracking(true);
  setMouseTracking(true);



}
```

Thats were i set mouse tracking twice
In objectloader.h
Then i define that method in objectloader.h

```
class ObjectLoader : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT


    public:
        explicit ObjectLoader(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~ObjectLoader();

    private slots:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    protected:

    private:

    };

    #endif // OBJECTLOADER_H
```

And implementation of that method in objectloader.cpp

```
void ObjectLoader::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){

    qDebug()<<"Mouse moved";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a mouse event is generated by Qt it is generally passed initially to the `QWidget` that was under the mouse pointer when the event was generated.  If that `QWidget` [accepts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accept) the event then no further processing will take place.  If the event *isn't* accepted then Qt may propogate the event to that `QWidget`'s parent and so on.

In your particular case the mouse move events you are interested in are being sent to the `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene` conponents where they are being accepted and, hence, no further processing takes place.  In a case like that you generally need to install an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) to intercept and process the events of interest.

Answer (score 1):

> Mouse move events will occur only when a mouse button is pressed down, unless mouse tracking has been enabled with QWidget::setMouseTracking().

So, I think you should check whether `mouseTracking` is **really** enabled or not, by using `[bool hasMouseTracking() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)'.

Comment: I am sure that it is enabled.When i run this code if(hasMouseTracking()){qDebug()<<"true";} It returns true

Comment: Could you post your source?

Comment: Update mouse events dont work on QtGraphicsView,but work on any other part of window?

Comment: `QMainWindow` has a [centralWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget). You should call `setMouseTracking()` for the `centralWidget` as well. So, in your `ObjectLoader` ctor, `centralWidget()->setMouseTracking(true)`.

Comment: Found out that QGraphicsScene does not accept MouseEvents but QGraphicsSceneMouseEvents,making implementation of that method did not help.Somehow like my GraphicsScene is black spot in window

Comment: The mouse move events are being 'consumed' by the `QGraphicsView` and/or the `QGraphicsScene`.  If you want to intercept and act on them them I think you'll have to install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).

Comment: @G.M. Do you want to post detailed answer with links and how to implement event filter,in order to help someone in future?